# How can I improve the responsiveness of my React component for different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm currently working on a React component that displays car information, including details, images, ratings, and comments. While the component looks fine on certain screen sizes, it's not adapting well to smaller or larger screens.

I've tried using CSS media queries and Material-UI's responsive design features, but I'm still encountering issues with layout consistency across different devices.

Here's my component structure:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Box, Paper, useMediaQuery, useTheme, Typography, Grid, Container, Accordion, AccordionSummary, AccordionDetails, Rating,
} from '@mui/material';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import FormGroup from '@mui/material/FormGroup';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import LocationOnIcon from './SVGiCON';

export const CarInfo: React.FC = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    gilad: false,
    jason: false,
    antoine: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
    });
  };

  const [ratingsExpanded, setRatingsExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const [commentsExpanded, setCommentsExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleRatingsExpandToggle = () => {
    setRatingsExpanded(!ratingsExpanded);
  };

  const handleCommentsExpandToggle = () => {
    setCommentsExpanded(!commentsExpanded);
  };

  const { gilad, jason, antoine } = state;
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number | null>(2);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Box
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
        minHeight="100vh"
      >
        <Paper
          elevation={3}
          sx={{
            p: '1.5rem', // Use rem units
            borderRadius: '1.25rem', // Use rem units
            textAlign: 'center',
            maxWidth: isMobile ? '100%' : 'xl',
            width: '68.75rem', // Use rem units
            backgroundColor: 'grey !important',
            overflow: 'hidden', // Ensure the container doesn't overflow
          }}
        >
          {/* Car Title */}
          <Typography variant="h4" gutterBottom color={'white'}>
            Car Title
          </Typography>

          <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
              {/* Add your car details here */}
              <Typography variant="body1" align="left">
                Собственик{' '}
                <Link to="/home" style={{ textDecoration: 'none', marginLeft: '0.625rem' }}>
                  <span style={{
                    color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'green', borderRadius: '1.25rem', padding: '0.625rem',
                  }}>
                    Александър Иванов
                  </span>
                </Link>
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem', marginTop: '1.25rem', marginBottom: '1.25rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                Костинброд, София-област
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                Детайли за колата:
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                Бензин
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                Черен
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                2022 г.
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem' }}>
                <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '0.625rem', width: '0.9375rem', height: '0.9375rem' }} />
                90 000 км
              </Typography>

              <FormGroup style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem', marginTop: '0.6875rem' }}>
                <FormControlLabel
                  style={{ marginBottom: '-0.625rem', color: "black" }}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={gilad}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      name="gilad"
                      size='small'
                      style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                  }
                  label="Реален пробег"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  style={{ color: "black" }}
                  control={
                    <Checkbox checked={jason}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      name="jason"
                      size='small'
                      style={{ color: 'black' }} />
                  }
                  label="Първи собственик"
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Grid>

            {/* Car Image (on the right for larger screens) */}
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
              {/* Add your image component here */}
              <div>
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
                  alt="Car"
                  style={{
                    width: '30.125rem', height: '17.25rem', objectFit: 'contain',
                  }} />
              </div>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ marginLeft: '2.5rem', marginTop: '2.5rem' }}>
            Лиценз
          </Typography>

          <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="flex-start" justifyContent="center">
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  position: 'relative',
                  width: '100%',
                  paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9 aspect ratio (modify as needed)
                  overflow: 'hidden',
                }}
              >
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/533669/pexels-photo-533669.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
                  alt="Car"
                  style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: '1.25rem',
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    left: '2.5rem',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    objectFit: 'cover', // or 'contain' depending on your preference
                  }} />
              </Box>
            </Grid>

            {/* Car Image (on the right for larger screens) */}
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6} container style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-start' }}>
              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginTop: '1.25rem' }}>
                Линк към документа{' '}
              </Typography>

              <Typography variant="body1" align="left" style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginTop: '1.25rem', wordBreak: 'break-all' }}>
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_certificate#/media/File:1917_auto_registration_license.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_certificate#/media/File:1917_auto_registration_license.jpg
                </a>
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6} marginLeft='2.5rem'>
            {/* Expandable Rating Section */}
            <Accordion
              expanded={ratingsExpanded}
              onChange={handleRatingsExpandToggle}
              sx={{
                marginTop: '1.25rem',
                width: '25%', // Adjusted width to 100%
                textAlign: 'left',
                backgroundColor: 'grey',
                border: 'none',
                boxShadow: 'none',
              }}
            >
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                id="panel1bh-header"
                style={{ padding: 0, backgroundColor: 'grey' }} // Remove padding
              >
                <Box flexDirection= 'column'>
                  <Typography variant="body1">Рейтинг</Typography>
                  <Rating name="read-only" value={value} readOnly size="large" />
                </Box>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>
                <div>
                  <Rating name="read-only" value={value} readOnly size="large" />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Rating name="read-only" value={value} readOnly size="large" />
                </div>
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>

            {/* Expandable Comments Section */}
            <Accordion
              expanded={commentsExpanded}
              onChange={handleCommentsExpandToggle}
              sx={{
                marginTop: '1.25rem',
                width: '25%', // Adjusted width to 100%
                textAlign: 'left',
                backgroundColor: 'grey',
                border: 'none',
                boxShadow: 'none',
              }}
            >
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                id="panel1bh-header"
                style={{ padding: 0, backgroundColor: 'grey' }} // Remove padding
              >
                <Typography variant="body1">Коментари</Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails style={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>
                <div>
                  <Typography variant="body2">
                    This is the first comment.
                  </Typography>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <Typography variant="body2">
                    Another comment goes here.
                  </Typography>
                </div>
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
          </Grid>
        </Paper>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CarInfo;
```

Here is how it looks on PC right now:

[image: Here is how it looks on PC right now]

Here is how it looks on mobile right now:

[image: Here is how it looks on mobile right now]

This is how it MUST look on PC and phone:

[image: This is how it MUST look on PC]

[image: This is how it MUST look on Phone]

I'm seeking advice on best practices and techniques for improving the responsiveness of my React component. Specifically, I'd like to know:

- How can I ensure that my component layout adjusts smoothly across various screen sizes and devices?
- Are there any common pitfalls or mistakes to avoid when designing responsive React components?
- What are some effective strategies for handling different viewport sizes and aspect ratios?
  Additionally, if there are any specific CSS frameworks, libraries, or tools that can facilitate responsive design in React applications, I'd appreciate recommendations.

Any insights, tips, or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with media queries as you've said you've tried, as well as designing the layout from the start to allow things to flow when the queries are applied. Without a specific, reproducible code I'm afraid this will probably be closed.

Comment: I'd suggest trying tailwind css, as its my personal choice. It has easy way to align your components based on the screen size such as `md:` / `sm:` / `lg:` / `xl:`  or just for classic media option if you don't want to use any styling frameworks.

Comment: using tailwind css is also a great option, you can responsive the component using tailwind and tailwind will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using different ways,

1. Use the tailwind CSS library for the responsiveness of the component.
2. Use CSS media queries along with viewport size you can customize it in the react JSX side.

Please check out the following example for a better understanding.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css'; // Import your CSS file for styling

function App() {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to check if the device is mobile
    const checkIfMobile = () => {
      const width = window.innerWidth;
      setIsMobile(width < 768); // You can adjust this threshold as needed
    };

    // Add event listener for window resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', checkIfMobile);

    // Initial check on component mount
    checkIfMobile();

    // Cleanup function to remove event listener
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', checkIfMobile);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>{isMobile ? 'Mobile View' : 'Desktop View'}</h1>
        {/* Render different components based on mobile or desktop */}
        {isMobile ? <MobileComponent /> : <DesktopComponent />}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

function MobileComponent() {
  return <div className="mobile-component">Mobile Component</div>;
}

function DesktopComponent() {
  return <div className="desktop-component">Desktop Component</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Example CSS code,

```
/* Example of CSS media queries */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mobile-component {
    /* Styles for mobile */
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .desktop-component {
    /* Styles for desktop */
    background-color: lightgreen;
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```